# Clustering polygons with cluster area limit

Tags: python, clustering

I have a polygon layer and I need to group polygons (basing on proximity) BUT there is a area limit for single cluster and limit for distance from cluster.

DBSCAN algorithm on centroids gives nice looking result, but I don't know how to incorporate cluster area limit in this method.

[image: DBSCAN result]

I've tried simple solution based on iteration:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

wydz['nr'] = -1
nr = 0
done_indexes = []

for index, row in wydz.iterrows():
    if index in done_indexes:
        continue
    nearest_polys = wydz.geometry.distance(row.geometry).sort_values()
    indexes = []
    pow_sum = 0
    for i in nearest_polys.iteritems():
        if i[0] not in done_indexes and i[1] < distance_limit:
            pow_sum += wydz.iloc[i[0]].geometry.area
            if pow_sum <= area_limit:
                indexes.append(i[0])
            else:
                break
    done_indexes += indexes
    for i in indexes:
        wydz.loc[i, 'nr'] = nr
    nr += 1
```

Unfortunatelly, the result is messy (polygons from one group stuck in the center of other groups, one group between two parts of other group, like in purple and brown etc.)

[image]

I am looking for groups as homogenic as in first picture, but with ability to set area and distance thresholds.
Anyone has idea how to solve this? It would be best to have this in Python.

Comment: It's a (very) ugly hack, but you can use the *kmeans* algorithm to do this. If you calculate the ratio : `total polygons area / max cluster area` you got a value, which (if it's rounded) give the number of classes to use for the partition. The algorithm should retruns some clusters with a maximal area near of the maximal value choose.

Comment: That is very interesting approach. I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Atm Well, it failed. 3/9 clusters are well over the area limit.

Comment: A lot ? This is probably due to the fact that there are dense areas isolated from the rest, so the algo groups them together. Maybe by being stricter on the maximum size it will work . Otherwise it seems to me that there is a variant of the HCA using geographical constraints (individuals are only grouped together if they are in contact), that might help (but you have to set the number of classes manually, not like DBSCAN). The only implementation I know of is on R : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustGeo/index.html